# How to redirect any route like "http://myweb.com/event/12" to my index.html using php?

Tags: php

I am trying to deploy my project on my `heroku`. My problem is that if I directly reload any route from the browser like:

```
http://mywebpage.com/event/12
```

I get "not found 404". I would like to do something so that by default I redirect to the `index.php/index.html` of my project. If I enter directly from my index in an internal navigation, I don't have any problem, like:

```
http://mywebpage.com
```

this is the structure of my folder:

```
index.php  this file is required by heroku and contains:
<?php header("Location: index.html"); ?>

index.html
css/
assets/
js/
```

Example of my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SGC</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.0f20b4a1e9dce59276ba.css"></head>
<body >
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/runtime.967e7535c76ed4c4fe77.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/polyfills.7037a817a5bb670ed2ca.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts.87f6e2e16f38d8ede974.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/main.372aa1d600b96fb16558.js"></script></body>

</html>
```

Comment: .htaccess options: FallBackResource, ErrorDocument, or a RewriteRule.

Comment: @mario is that posibble config in heroku? how?